# Can't access property sourceIndexPath on UIDragItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a viewcontroller that contains two separate UICollectionViews. I'm allowing for cells to be dragged from one UICollectionView to another. 
In the method

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView performDropWithCoordinator:(id<UICollectionViewDropCoordinator>)coordinator;
```

I get the dragged item like this

```
UIDragItem *item = [coordinator.items objectAtIndex:0];
```

To determine if the drag originated from the same UICollectionView, I want to check the property `sourceIndexPath` on the `item`object as documented on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdropitem/2897392-sourceindexpath?language=objc 
Unfortunately, Xcode keeps telling me `Property 'sourceIndexPath' not found on object of type 'UIDragItem *'`
When I print out `item`, I clearly see the property is available, the nil value is of no importance here, it indicates the drag source.

```
<_UICollectionViewDropItem:0x60000189a760 previewSize = {50, 50}; sourceIndexPath = (nil); dragItem = <_UIDropItem: 0x60000240a0a0>>
```

I'm really stuck here, and feels like I'm forgetting to implement some protocol, but double triple checked and everything seems fine. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue where sourceIndexPath is always nil.

Answer (score -3):

Please try https://cocoapods.org/pods/DragDropiOS This will help you.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let model = collectionModels[indexPath.item]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DragDropCollectionViewCell.IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! DragDropCollectionViewCell

        cell.updateData(model)

        return cell
    }
```